# Reading multiple xml file in a folder

Tags: java, xml

The code I posted is all working and is for writing but I need advice for how do I read the xml file so I can output it and/or delete the file. I read about SAX, documentbuilder .parse method and few others but I am confused on what do I use. I do not need you to write code for this but to point me in right direction.

The files are created in a folder separately so I need to read them all at once if possible (the name of the file is the variable listed below as **Id**)

This is how I create XML files.

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    {
    try {
        DocumentBuilder doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc1=doc.newDocument();

        Element IdNumber = (Element) doc1.createElement(Id);
        Element IDes=(Element) doc1.createElement("InitialDestination");
        Element FinDes=(Element) doc1.createElement("FinalDestination");
        Element HourTime=(Element) doc1.createElement("Hours");
        Element Minutetime=(Element) doc1.createElement("Minutes");
        Element Price=(Element) doc1.createElement("TicketPrice");
        Element Tran=(Element) doc1.createElement("TransportAgency");

        doc1.appendChild(IdNumber);

        IDes.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(InDes));
        FinDes.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(FDes));
        HourTime.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(Htime));
        Minutetime.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(Mtime));
        Price.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(TicketPrice));
        Tran.appendChild(doc1.createTextNode(TransportAgency));

        IdNumber.appendChild(IDes);
        IdNumber.appendChild(FinDes);
        IdNumber.appendChild(HourTime);
        IdNumber.appendChild(Minutetime);
        IdNumber.appendChild(Price);
        IdNumber.appendChild(Tran);

        Source S=new DOMSource(doc1);
        File file1=new File("C:\\Users\\Lozanovski\\Desktop\\TransportMe");
        file1.mkdirs();
        File file=new File("C:\\Users\\Lozanovski\\Desktop\\TransportMe\\"+Id+".xml");
        StreamResult R=new StreamResult(file);
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(S, R);
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException except)
    {
        System.out.println(except);
    }
    catch(TransformerException  except1)
    {
        System.out.println(except1);
    }
    catch(DOMException except2)
    {
        System.out.println(except2);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException except3){
        System.out.println(except3);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to properly post xml code (I will accept edit)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    -<InsertIdentificationNumber>

    <InitialDestination>Insert Initial Destination</InitialDestination>

    <FinalDestination>Insert Final Destination</FinalDestination>

    <Hours>Insert Hours</Hours>

    <Minutes>Insert Minutes</Minutes>

    <TicketPrice>Insert Ticket Price</TicketPrice>

    <TransportAgency>Insert Transport Agency</TransportAgency>

    </InsertIdentificationNumber>
```

Comment: You want to read a XML file into a DOM ?

Comment: yes, i want to read into DOM so i can use the name of the file to delete it or output all content inside the file in a new frame

Comment: Than you have already the answer, see @Khalids post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through the folder, and for each file found, create a `Document` and use it to display/output the content. You can also delete the file if needed:

```
File folder = new File("C:\\Users\\Lozanovski\\Desktop\\TransportMe");
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

if (folder.isDirectory()) {
    for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(file); // create an XML document
        file.delete(); // delete the file
    }
}
```

Comment: i am getting an error that cannot be resolved on the parsing line, even i changed to docBuilder.parse(file) because you have spelling mistake and it does't working again.

Comment: You need to create the `DocumentBuilder` first. See the updated code.

Comment: i fixed that error i have another errors which i will reply later if i cannot solve

Comment: This is not how you display the content of a `Document`. You need to loop through the hierarchy and display the tag names and/or text content. Review the JavaDocs to see how to get the elements in the document. For example, try this: `System.out.println(doc1.getElementsByTagName("InitialDestination").item(0).getTextContent());`.

Comment: i have found a solution for my problem, thanks anyway.